# Adjusting Central Meridian in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

How can I adjust the central meridian of a built-in projection in ArcGIS Pro? I'm using version 1.1.1.3309.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That functionality has not been added yet. One solution is to modify a projected coordinate system in ArcMap, then use the Save As option to store it as a .prj file. In Pro, you can import a .prj file directly or use an existing feature class.

[image: ArcGIS Pro map property page]

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the projection and click "Copy and Modify" and then you can change whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019, you can do the following in ArcGIS Pro:

- Right click on map, select Properties to open the Map Properties
  module.
- Select Coordinate Systems Look to the right for a globe icon
  with a green plus sign, select to access "Add Coordinate System"

[image: Screenshot showing the Add Coordinate System dropdown]

- Select New Projected Coordinate System to bring up the following dialog box.

[image: New Projected Coordinate System dialog box in ArcGIS Pro]

- In the Name row, change the name to something that you'll remember.
- In the Projection row, click on the right cell to use the drop down menu to select your projection.
- In the Central meridian row, enter your value.
- Save and use your new projection with your adjusted meridian.